# NodeJS Firebase wait for request

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

How do I wait for all the Firebase requests to be fulfilled?

I have an array of user phones - `array`.

**Step 1**: Create an array of all user phones and generate a unique ticket identifier. (`randomStringIdent()` - line generation function)

```
var arrayTikets = {};
var AllArrayPhone = []
array.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
    AllArrayPhone.push(item.stringValue)
    arrayTikets[item.stringValue]=randomStringIdent(50)
});
```

**Step 2**: I break down `AllArrayPhone` into 10 (since Firebase does not support more than 10 conditions). I request Firebase and create an array of users that are in the database.

```
var regusers = [];
const splitArray = AllArrayPhone.chunk(10);

for (const items of splitArray) {
    let usersRef = db.collection('users');
    let users = await usersRef.where('userphone', 'in', items);
    let userdocs = users.get();


    for (SingDoc of userdocs.docs) {
        regusers.push(SingDoc._fieldsProto.userphone.stringValue)
    }



    console.log("data pushed")
}
```

**Step 3**: Writing to Firebase the resulting array from Step 2.

```
admin.firestore().doc(path).update({Users: regusers,Status: 1})
```

**Step 4**: Recording the generated ticket IDs from step 1

```
for (var key in arrayTikets) {
    db.collection('events').doc(id).collection("tickets").doc(key).set({ticket:arrayTikets[key]});
}
```

**Step 5**: Making a note in the notification log

```
for (item of regusers) {
    let DocRef = db.collection('notifications').doc(item);
     DocRef.update({notif.doc: 'NEW'});
}
```

How do I consistently perform all these cycles? Do I start to perform the next step only after the previous step?

Comment: Did you tried use promises to control this flow? This lib can be helpful https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: @rpereira15 - Presumably at least some of this is using promises, as the OP is using `await`, which is only valid in `async` functions (which create promises) and only useful when used on a promise.

Comment: Sergo, can you clarify your question? You've asked *"How do I consistently perform all these cycles? Do I start to perform the next step only after the previous step?"* How else would you do it? Many of these steps use the results of previous steps, so you couldn't overlap them...?